# C Initializer element is not constant [What's the difference between array and variable]

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code-piece

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int a[4];
 int b;
 struct test {
         int *ptr;
         int val;
 };

 struct test test_array[] = {
         {
                 a, //Don't understand here
                 b  //compile error 
         }
 };

 int main() {
         struct test ha = test_array[0];
         ha.ptr[0] = 10;
         printf("%d\n", ha.ptr[0]);
         return 0;
 }
```

from the following link, I know why the compile error happens.
[C - initializer element is not constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602159/c-initializer-element-is-not-constant)

But just don't understand why static storage array is OK?

Thanks

Comment: Syntax issues aside, what were you thinking when you thought it would make sense to initialize a variable with the value of another uninitialized variable?

Comment: @Lundin I presume this source here is not supposed to be the finished version.

Comment: @Lundin: Variables with static storage duration are *always* initialized.

Comment: @KerrekSB My comment is just a call for common sense. Sure you don't think it makes sense to write `val=b` to initialize `val` to zero, just because you know that `b`, having static storage duration, is implicitly initialized to zero? Rather than writing `val=0;` in the first place.

Comment: Actually I make mistake for b, and I just try whether array [i.e. 'a'] is OK or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initializers of global variables in C need to be constant expressions, and `b` is not a constant expression. (It's not even a `const` variable.) By contrast, the expression `a` is the *address* of the first element of the global array `a`, and addresses of global variables *are* constant expressions.

To answer your question at a higher level: The difference between `a` and `b` is that you are using the *value* of `b` but not the value of `a`, only its *address*.

Answer (score 0):

b is not constant, as pointed out earlier. As for a, the variable's content is not constant either but all you take in your struct is the address of that array. And that is constant and known at compile time.

Comment: This answer is a bit loose: If you said `const int a = 3;` at file scope, the constant would be known at compile time, yet [C doesn't allow it as an initializer](https://ideone.com/jU2Xw7). Ultimately, the answer is that that's how C is specified, unsatisfying as that may be. It just doesn't have a very sophisticated concept of constant expressions.

Comment: True, you said it better. But you get the idea.

Comment: The upshot is that thinking about the detailed operation of a compiler isn't generally useful for understanding a language... Something that makes perfect sense to a human might make no sense to C.